# Excel VBA userform : "Change Event" of Combobox when fired executes the code in the "ButtonClick Event"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a combobox named *ReportList* in userform. I am writing some code in two of its events - ***DropButtonClick()*** and ***Change()***.

In ***DropButtonClick()*** event, the combox is cleared and repopulated with entries of column A.

In ***Change()*** event, I am filling a few textboxes with values related to the selected entry in combobox.

What is happening is, the code in ***DropButtonClick()*** event is getting executed as intended but as soon as I select an entry from the combobox drop down, instead of the ***Change()*** event  getting fired, the code inside ***DropButtonClick()*** event is getting executed again. Is this a bug or am I missing something ?

```
Private Sub ReportList_DropButtonClick()
   
    'Debug.Print "Event Triggered"  '
    Dim DB_Sheet As Worksheet
    Set DB_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataBase")
    Dim LstRow As Long
    LstRow = DB_Sheet.Cells(DB_Sheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long
    ReportList.Clear
    For i = 3 To LstRow
      ReportList.AddItem (DB_Sheet.Range("A" & i).value)
    Next
      
End Sub

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub ReportList_Change()

  If ReportList.value <> "" Then
     ' Some code here to get the rownumber of selected entry in combobox
      ReportAuthor.value = DB_Sheet.Range(NumToLet(1) & RowNumber).value
      ReportType.value = DB_Sheet.Range(NumToLet(2) & RowNumber).value
  End if

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/developer/sequence-of-events-in-excel-combobox/m-p/191973) document which tells the sequence of events in a Combobox.

At the link, it is said that the sequence of events one would expect to see would be:

- DropButtonClick
- Click
- Change

Instead, what happens is:

- DropButtonCLick
- Change
- Click

Comment: Thanks but the thread doesn't have an answer, may be that's why somebody downvoted it. On the bright side, now we know that the issue is universal.